# Chosen Plug-in still not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to use the Chosen jquery plugin, i have all the right files but i can't call the function correctly. I took a look at the java error console, it loads but i get the error:

```
Error: $(".chzn-select").chosen is not a function
Source File: http://localhost:3000/javascripts/application.js?1312657233
```

This is my application.js( the only thing inside of it):

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('.chzn-select').chosen();
});
```

This the form code i am using:

```
<%= select("user_product", "product_id", Product.all.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }, {},{:class=>'chzn-select'}) %>
```

javascript folder:

```
application.js
chosen.jquery.js
jquery_ujs.js
jquery.js
jquery.min.js
jquery.tokeninput.js
```

How do i call this correctly so i can get this working or maybe a change in my form?

Comment: What is the content of your javascript folder? Sometimes it's not about things that are missing, but about things that should not be there.

Comment: I included my javascript folder. I removed the tokeninput.js before and it still didn't work.

Comment: And when you check your page's HTML source do you see all these files being included?

Comment: No! what the...how do i fix this? my jquery.min.js and chosen.jquery.js isnt showing up. Good call!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your `app/view/layout/application.html.erb` view and add `<%= javascript_include_tag "chosen.jquery" %>` and `<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery.min" %>`. It should include what's missing.